# Replace ajax url with clicked element which have data attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, custom-data-attribute

My question is very simple for jquery lovers, but hard for me. I have simple `a href` tag with data atrribute included.

```
<a href="#/one" data-menu-button="menu1" class="button">menu 1</a>
<a href="#/two" data-menu-button="menu2" class="button">menu 2</a>

// etc
```

Also i have very simple ajax call script.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test.php", success: function(result){
           $(".page").html(result);
        }});
});
```

**My question:**

How can i replace ajax url with clicked button data atrribute? For example, at the moment, as you can see, i have `url: "test.php"`. What i need, is to change `test` to data atrribute (for example: `menu1`), but keep .php extension. I need that script finds clicked data atrribute, and replace it with `test`. Maybe `$(this)` would work?

Thanks for any answers, and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)** to fetch the value from data attributes.

Use `$(this).data('menu-button')` to fetch from `data-menu-button` and then append `.php` to it. It would look like `menu1.php`. `$(this)` would refer to the current element which is clicked.

You would also have to use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the page from navigating to whatever is present in href attribute. Unless you want to page url to have those fragments.

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url: $(this).data('menu-button') + '.php', success: function(result){
       $(".page").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have guessed use `$(this)` to access the element, then `.attr('data-menu-button)` to get the attribute value.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('data-menu-button') + '.php';
    $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
       $(".page").html(result);
    }});
})
```

Comment: Thanks to you too, but @Dhiraj Bodicherla was faster with good explanation :)